# Is there a copy of the 5E SRD in Libreoffice or Word format?

Tags: dnd-5e, ogl

Is there a copy of the 5E SRD in LibreOffice or Word format? I attempted to covert it myself, but were unable to. The only copies I can find are in PDF format or wiki format.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [Markdown SRD5](https://github.com/gguillotte/mdsrd5) includes [a Word conversion](https://github.com/gguillotte/mdsrd5/blob/master/mdsrd5.docx). Click **View Raw** to download it.

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: A note from the first link: "This project is no longer maintained. For an up-to-date, accessible, searchable SRD, see http://5e.d20srd.org/." That said, the linked docx file was last updated in April 2016, and [the SRD hasn't been updated since January 2016](https://dnd.wizards.com/articles/features/systems-reference-document-srd), so it shouldn't actually be out of date.